# Codeigniter & Jquery Ajax, working on Localhost but not on Server, 404 Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

> This one took a whole day to figure out. And no matter how silly it
>   may sound but it was what it was, a silly spelling mistake, not
>   exactly a spelling mistake, I spelled controllers in the
>   **application>modules>Contact>controllers** as **application>modules>Contact>Controllers** see the capitalization of the 'C' of the controllers. :|

I tried the target url with the trailing '/' and without '/' and I tried to provide url manually to the ajax function instead of fetching it from the `action` attribute of the `<form>` but nothing worked. **I keep getting Error 404** what's going on ?

1. alert (  jqXHR.responseText  ); **Returns 404 html**
2. alert (  textStatus  ); **Returns string 'error'**
3. alert (  errorThrown  ); **Returns string 'Not Found'**

I am using wiredesignz HMVC and Controller Contact resides in application>modules>Contact>controllers>Contact.php

> One thing to mention, For some reason I can not access
>   http://example.com/Contact if I try to access it via url in a browser,
>   I always get error 404. both on localhost and online
>
> Although I can access other controllers/pages on the website

**FORM HTML**

```
<form id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal subscribe" accept-charset="utf-8" action="<?= base_url ( 'Contact/' ); ?>" method="post">
    <!--Name-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="name">Name</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control validate" name="name" placeholder="Your full name" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Email-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
            <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control validate" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Message-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="message">Message</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Submit Button-->
    <div class="form-group text-right">
        <input id="contact_us" type="hidden" name="contact_us" value="Submit" />

        <button type="submit" id="contact_us" class="btn btn-warning" name="contact_us" value="Submit">
            Send &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
$( '#contact-form' ).submit ( function ( event ) {

    event.preventDefault (  );
    event.stopPropagation (  );

    var $scriptUrl = $( '#contact-form' ).attr ( 'action' );

    var $data = new FormData( $( '#contact-form' ) [ 0 ] );
    $data.append ( 'myUrl', window.location.href );

    $.ajax ( {
        method : 'POST',
        url : $scriptUrl,
        data    : $data,
        cache : false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function ( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
            if ( data.success === true ) { alert ('success'); }
            else { alert ('failure'); }
        },
        error : function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            alert (  jqXHR.responseText  );
        }
    } );

} );
</script>
```

**Controller** *(http://example.com/Contact)*

```
/*I am testing with print_r($_POST); only for the time being*/

<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Contact extends  MX_Controller {

    private $data;

    public function __construct (  )
    {
        $this->data['stylesheets'] = [ 'welcome' ];
        $this->data['javascripts'] = [ 'welcome' ];
    }

    public function index (  )
    {
        print_r($_POST);
    }
}
```

*.htaccess*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 


<Files "index.php">
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>  
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you modify your .htaccess for rewrite rules? First check if you are getting desired output using http://mysite/index.php/contact. Keep the controller name lowercase.

Comment: Can you just check the base url once? I think the base url is not configured properly. Also check the request string in browser's dev tool. What I could understand is that the request is hitting the wrong url instead.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma I checked, it is hitting the correct url, base url is correct as well since I can access other pages/controller of the website

Comment: @SanketR the mysite/index.php/contact did not work. I have updated my question with the .htaccess, please have a look

Comment: What's uri_protocol in your config.php file? Is it set to REQUEST_URI?

Comment: @SanketR Yes it is set to REQUEST_URI

Comment: You have another class called Contact, that is not a controller? It may be a conflict of names.

Comment: Can you post your entire controller code here?

Comment: @OvidiuBadita No, Just one class.

Comment: @SanketR I have updated the controller code above.

Comment: You should call parent::construct() in your controller constructor.

Comment: @OvidiuBadita Didn't work.

Comment: What are you using wamp or xampp

Comment: @wolfgang1983 wamp

Comment: @StudentX Make sure your mod rewrite is enabled and try some of these https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: Try and rename the controller with something else and see if it works. It may still be a name conflict. If after rename, you can access the route, at least you know where to look. If all other routes work, except for this one, I am convinced it is a naming conflict of some kind. - @StudentX